# Linq join and tenary query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join, c#-4.0

I am trying  to do a join with a tenary expression as shown following.
The "AddedSince" is calculated in the model from the date the customer was added, The period is a dynamic and it is picked from the url query parameter.

What I am trying to achieve  is to  check if the person has been added at a shorter period than the period requested if so use the AddedSince value.  There are other joins and  all work well except this one I am not sure am doing it right.  The error is that "int does not contain a definition for CustomerId"

```
int period =6;
var query =( from bk in customers..... 

 join cu in db.Customers.Where(a=>a.MemberOk).Select(a => a.AddedSince < period ? a.AddedSince: period)
on bk.CustomerId equals cu.CustomerId into cuspd  )
```

can I use a tenery operation in this way at all with linq?  if yes how do I do this.  Thanks

Comment: You are projecting every customer into an int property, and then trying join on `int.CustomerId`.

Comment: `What I am trying to achieve is to check if the person has been added at a shorter period than the period requested if so use the AddedSince value` what do you mean by _using_? selecting that value? joining on that value?

Comment: I need customerId  and  AddedSince or Period value to join  the query

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tenary operator, but you can not add the select in the middle of join.

Instead, you can do the join as normal and then perform the select, ie

```
int period =6;
var query = (from bk in customers.....   
             join cu in db.Customers on bk.CustomerId equals cu.CustomerId   
             where cu.MemberOk
             select a.AddedSince < period ? a.AddedSince: period
             );
```

The `.Where(a=>a.MemberOk)` section could be left where you have it, but I have moved it to avoid mixing query and lamba styles.